# Creating Indented DIVs using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to develop a page that we can use to organize a magazine. There will be multiple sections to the magazine that will contain multiple pages, each page may have multiple articles on them. To accomplish this, I want to have a DIV for each page or section that will intent to show that it's subordinate to the group above it. Here's a picture of what I want it to look like:

http://chromaticinc.com/help/final.png

I'd like to only use CSS to accomplish this. So far, I've come up with this:

http://chromaticinc.com/help/

But it is using Javascript to set the width on the 1st column, because each of the other columns has to line up too and with the variable width on the 1st column, it throws off the layout. I'm sure I could use Javascript to set the width of the "Comments" column, but I feel like there has to be a better solution using CSS.

I'm open to using tables, if it would make sense, but each item will have to be draggable so that they can be rearranged and also they will have to be able to be moved into other sections, so I've set them in DIVs to make that easier.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would consider using nested, styled unordered lists. They have good semantic meaning.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. I will definitely consider doing that, but I still can't figure out how I can make the columns line up without using Javascript.

Comment: Show some html? Existing CSS?

Comment: If you can make a fixed-width wrapper for the columns and center it, things should line up fine. You may have to absolutely-position the pane label though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using [relative positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

You will want to give the element an id and then use some CSS like this:

```
#divid {
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
}
```

This will force the div to move over however much you specify from its default position.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am actually using a class and setting a left margin, that way further nesting will also produce the indent. The problem is keeping column 2 lined up, because I don't know how many levels of indenting there will be.

Comment: In that case you could use absolute positioning for the elements inside of the div. The absolute value for the left offset will force the elements to line up.